# how to conditionally add attributes to start_lvl() function?

Tags: walker

I want to add the id of the parent element in a container div of children elements. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
<?php
  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul id=\"Here I want to tell wordpress to put the ID of parent element\" class=\"collapse\">\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the data you need in the `start_lvl()` method to do this. That data is available in the `start_el()` method in the `$item` variable, so you will have to cook up a way to pass that data along:

```
class my_extended_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  var $prnt = 0;
  var $pdepth = false;

  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $id = '';
    if (!empty($this->prnt)) {
      $id = 'id="prnt-'.$this->prnt.'"';
    }
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul $id class=\"collapse\">\n";
  }

  public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    if ($this->pdepth !== $depth) {
      $this->prnt = $item->ID;
      $this->pdepth = $depth;
    } else {
      $this->prnt = $this->pdepth = 0;
    }
    parent::start_el($output,$item,$depth,$args,$id);
  }
}
// testing
wp_nav_menu( 
  array( 
    'walker'=>new my_extended_walker(),
    'menu' => 'mymenu'
  ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried another way around and it works. Simply in start_el function, I get $output from start_level, using str_replace, change what I want to change! that's it. so simple! and again, thank you so much. By the way, I want to vote up for your answer, but unfortunately my reputation is not enough :(

Comment: @pershianix you should be able to accept the answer to close your question -  more on how to do that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/270140).